# During inheritance, is the base class's base classes inherited also?

Tags: c++, inheritance, syntax, polymorphism

There is a game engine that I am making and I have a GameObject class. This Gameobject class is the base class, which a Model class inherits from. Now, a Cube class inherits from Model.

Therefore, I was wondering if the Cube class would therefore be able to access members from the GameObject class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as the functions or variables are declared as public or protected, you can access them from inherited classes.

i.e.

```
class GameObject{
public:
  int getID(void);
};

class Model : public GameObject{
};

class Cube : public Model{
  int useID( void ){
    return getID() + 5;
  }
};
```

/Henrik

Comment: Seems like everyone apart from me knows the answer to this

Answer (score 2):

Yes - Except the private ones. can access both the protected or public ones

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as long as the base class isn't private, or the members concerned.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but they have to be public or protected. See the [base class member access table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7f45fat0.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

It depends on kind on inheritance you opt for. So if B is going to inherit A... then following are possibilities...

```
B:public A
B:protected A
B:private A ( which is similar to B : A )
```

Each kind of inheritance has is its own nature... and it will affect what all a child class can access from its parent. 
Also each kind of inheritance... has its own advantages and disadvantages.

And in most of the cases... public inheritance is used... and its there Henrik's answer explains everything.